# SQL Groupby for values in sorted time sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

Table A:

```
|    type    |  message  |          createdAt         | 
|:----------:|:---------:|:--------------------------:|
| create     |  awesome  | 2017-07-21 11:20:35.147629 |     
| create     |  hello    | 2017-07-21 11:20:35.147629 |    
| create     |  good     | 2017-07-22 10:20:34.123331 |     
| upload     |  nope     | 2017-07-22 11:28:08.815828 |      
| create     |  test     | 2017-07-22 11:29:35.147629 |    
| create     |  hello    | 2017-07-22 12:20:35.147629 |
```

Desired output:

```
|  type  |  new_message |       new_createdAt        |
|:------:|:------------:|:--------------------------:|
| create |      3       | 2017-07-22 10:20:34.123331 |
| upload |     nope     | 2017-07-22 11:28:08.815828 |
| create |      2       | 2017-07-22 12:20:35.147629 |
```

The SQL statement should combine similar `type` only if they are in sequence of `createdAt`. If number of similar `type` value in a sequence is more than 1 then `new_message` is the count else `new_message` is the same as `message` (This if-else clause is not the most important feature, a statement which just gives the count is also fine).

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Is it possible to add another factor in the time series, group only if the difference between the lowest and the highest `createdAt` is say X.

e.g. if I choose X=24 hours, the output for Table A will change to:

```
|  type  |  new_message |       new_createdAt        |
|:------:|:------------:|:--------------------------:|
| create |      2       | 2017-07-21 11:20:35.147629 |
| create |     good     | 2017-07-22 10:20:34.123331 |
| upload |     nope     | 2017-07-22 11:28:08.815828 |
| create |      2       | 2017-07-22 12:20:35.147629 |
```

Is there a way to do so without a `JOIN`.

Comment: Solved the time interval problem (**UPDATE** part) using [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/127874)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use difference of `ROW_NUMBER`s:

```
WITH CteRn AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY createdAt)
          - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY createdAt) AS rn
    FROM Tbl
)
SELECT
    type,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR(30)) 
        ELSE MAX(cte.message)
    END AS message,
    MAX(cte.createdAt) AS createdAt
FROM CteRn cte
GROUP BY cte.type, cte.rn
ORDER BY MAX(cte.createdAt);
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://rextester.com/NSL30671)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using the difference of row numbers and then aggregation, with a single subquery:

```
select type,
       (case when count(*) = 1 then max(message) else count(*)::text end) as message,
       min(created_at) as new_createdAt
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by createdAt) as seqnum_c,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by createdAt) as seqnum_tc
      from t
     ) t
group by type, (seqnum_c - seqnum_tc)
order by new_createdAt;
```